# Unable to delete the Application(.apk) on IBM Worklight V6.1 application center

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

I would like to ask on how to delete an application in IBM worklight application center.

When i select the application and click delete then click ok and click apply. The application is not deleted.

Comment: Have you checked server logs?

Comment: There must already be something wrong after you click ok. Normally, in the application details, you click "Delete" then "Ok", but then the application details get closed, so the "Apply" button disappears. There is no need to click any "Apply" button. Without looking at the server logs, it is not possible to determine what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In the Application Center Console, select the application version to go to the application properties page. There, select the delete button and confirm the dialog. This deletes the application version. Note, if you have many versions of the same application, it only deletes the current version. You will still see all other versions.

What I describe seems the same as what you do accoprding to your own description. If it does not work for you, please check the server logs. What you report is not normal, so I suspect there is a configuration error somewhere and most likely you see exceptions in the server log that help to determine what is wrong.